# WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've got error "WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET /web/board/getBoardList"

Please help to find my mistakes....
It seems to be a problem with servlet-context.xml.

This is my package hierarchy.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrQXq.png)

**BoardController.java**

```
package com.jione.web.board.controller;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.jione.web.board.service.BoardService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/board")

public class BoardController {

    @Inject
    private BoardService boardService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getBoardList", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getBoardList(Model model) throws Exception {
        model.addAttribute("boardList", boardService.getBoardList());
        return "board/index";

    }

}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee https://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/*-context.xml</param-value> 
        <!--  <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value> -->
    </context-param>
    
    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:servlet-context.xml</param-value>
            <!-- <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value> -->
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
        
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Character Set Filter -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
        </filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**servlet-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc https://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context https://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->
    
    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    
    
    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
    
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.jione" />
    
</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Why the /web in the path?

Comment: @Vladimir Now found. The path is wrong. Thanks to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Adding this as a solution, also. The path was wrong, it also included `/web`, but the controller didn't that part of the path mapped.